# Teledyne relay 420

Tags: relay

I'm using teledyne relay 420 in our project. Can anyone help me out with its pin functions and connections?

The datasheet is here    http://www.teledynerelays.com/pdf/electromechanical/420422.pdf

In the schematic diagram for 420 relay  shown in the datasheet there is a point where ends of the coil are connected. What is that small circle? There isn't any  pin on the i.c that comes out from that point. There are only 8 pins.

Comment: What is the full part number? There seem to be different packages for the 420 relay.

Comment: That appears to represent a case ground.  Are their any pins connected to the outside of the metal can?

Comment: There are no pins connected to outside of metal can..There are exactly 8 pins. I'm just wondering how to give the coil voltage with this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the last page of the data sheet and you'll see that that's a case ground.   It *is* a pin, but it's part of the header and the minus end of each coil is connected to it internally.

**EDIT:**

If you start with the tab and count clockwise looking at the bottom of the can, the ground pin will be between pins 4 and 5. From the data sheet it appears that it's not a lead, it's only a pin and it's only 0.01" high, so that may be a problem for you if you're expecting a lead there.  In any case, you'll need to use the case as as your ground connection for the coils, with pin 4 being the other end of COIL A, and pin 8 being the other end of COIL B. If you need ground leads for the relay coils, then you might want to order 422s.

Note, from the data sheet: "SCHEMATICS ARE VIEWED FROM TERMINALS CONTACTS SHOWN IN POSITION RESULTING WHEN COIL A LAST ENERGIZED".

Note also that when coil "B" is activated, BOTH sets of contacts will change over and latch from how they're shown on the data sheet, and then change back and latch when coil "A" is later activated.

Comment: I couldn't exactly get what you meant. In short can you please tell how to supply power to coil. I mean where should i give the vlotage

Comment: @student: Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are asking about this diagram:

[image]

This is meant to somewhat correlate visually to the bottom of the can.  The extra rings around 8 of the pins are meant to look a little like the insulation between the pin and the case.  Take a look at the bottom of a real part and you'll see what I mean.  The bottom pin is connected directly to the case, so there is no gap filled with some insulating material, and it is shown without this extra ring.

Some reasons you might care about this:

All the other conductors in the device will have some capacitive coupling to the case.  You want the case to therefore be connected to AC ground.

The case will act like a shield, so you want to connect it to something that can drain away the small amount of current it picks up from capacitive coupling to elsewhere.

If you clamp this part to something to a heat sink or anything else conductive, you need to know what node all that will be connected to.